# Alignment problem when redefining the table of contents (toc)

Tags: table-of-contents, renewcommand

I want to redefine the table of contents like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \setlength\@tempdima{2.3em}%
  \noindent\hspace*{1.5em}\large\textbf{#1}\par%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


The content...
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\section{Section 5}
\section{Section 6}
\end{document}
```

but when i compile the document (pdfTex), the number 1 (of the first section in the ToC) is not aligned with the other numbers.

Do you know how to solve this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry. Here it is.

Comment: Maybe It will be easer by using `titlesec titletoc` package

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tocloft` package :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
%   \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
%   \setlength\@tempdima{2.3em}%
%   \noindent\hspace*{1.5em}\large\textbf{#1}\par%
% }
% \makeatother


\begin{document}
\renewcommand\cftsecnumwidth{5em}
\renewcommand\cftpagenumbersoff

\tableofcontents


The content...
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\section{Section 5}
\section{Section 6}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but i don't want to print the page number. Is it possible ?

Comment: `\cftpagenumbersoff` The command \cftpagenumbersoff{hentryi}` will eliminate the page numbers
for hentryi in the listing, where hentryi is the name of one of the standard kinds
of entries (e.g., subsection, or figure — including subfigure if the subfigure
package is used — etc.), or the name of a new entry defined with the tocloft
package.